# How to feed log4j.properies to dropwizard?

Tags: apache, dropwizard, log4j

I am starting the server by using the following command:

```
java -cp target.jar application_name server configuration.yml
```

Now how do you feed a file having log4j properties into the above command?

Or we have to make some changes in YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard did not work with log4j till 1.2.4.

For dropwizard version >= 1.2.4 you can pass log4j configurations as shown in the below example

https://github.com/arteam/dropwizard-nologback/